# Is there any way to convert a literal to a non literal variable in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, replace, literals

My goal is to have an array that includes specific commands for each value. However to even get bash to process the array I need to create literal values surrounded by `''`

When trying to process through the array the literal values (that include variable syntax) are processed as their literal name instead of their variable name. Is there anyway to convert a literal value to a non literal value?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
dir=C
echo "Non literal"
ls $dir
echo "Literal"
'ls $dir'
echo "variable with literal
cmd='ls $dir'
echo $cmd
echo "$cmd"

$ ./test.sh
Non literal
01_hello_world  Modern_C  PLE_LinkedIn_Learning_C  The_C_Programming_Language
Literal
./test.sh: line 6: ls $dir: command not found
variable with literal
ls $dir
ls $dir
```

From the "Literal statement" I want to be able to convert `'ls $dir'` to `"ls $dir"` so `$dir` gets processed as `C`.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

I want to include my actual script that will process a list of commands from an array (my original goal):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

dir=C
tree_cmd=tree

run_cmds(){
    if [[ -z "$@" ]]; then
        echo "Array is empty"
    else
        for i in "$@"; do
            $i
        done
    fi
}

arr=(
'ls $dir'
'cat $dir/01_hello_world'
'$tree_cmd $dir'
)

run_cmds "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: Are you looking for `eval 'ls $dir'`?   Even in that case, you should quote the `dir` and use `eval 'ls "$dir"'`, but ... there is almost certainly a better way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Note that although `eval "$cmd"` almost certainly "solves" your immediate problem, it opens up a whole can of worms that you probably don't want to have to worry about.

Comment: The shell does not have the kind of distinction you claim between literal and non-literal values.  Your issue is about quoting and its effect on parameter expansion.  This is not part of values, but rather an attribute of the specific *commands* used to assign values.

Comment: `My goal is to have an array that includes specific commands for each value` Can we concentrate on the goal? What do you mean by "specific commands for each value"? What value, value of what? Could explain what you want, ignoring all the "literal non-literal" stuff?

Comment: @KamilCuk I updated my post to include the context of a test array script I built. Notice my array has commands that reference variables, I want to pass that to a function that will run each command (value) from the array. Does that help?

Comment: `$dir=C` is invalid. `$($i)` is odd.

Comment: @KamilCuk woops! yes fixed the variable. re: `$($i)` your right adjusted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not store commands in strings. Use functions.

Quote variable expansion.

Use shellcheck to check your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=C
tree_cmd=tree

run_cmds(){
    if ((!$#)); then
        echo "No argumetns given"
    else
        local i
        for i in "$@"; do
            "$i"
        done
    fi
}

cmd_1() {
       ls "$dir"
}
cmd_2() {
       cat "$dir"/01_hello_world
}
cmd_3() {
      "$tree_cmd" "$dir"
}
arr=( cmd_1 cmd_2 cmd_3 )

run_cmds "${arr[@]}"
```

If you really want to store commands in strings, for example for short testing purposes, ignoring some best practices, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 . Still quote variable expansions. You can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=C
tree_cmd=tree

run_cmds(){
    local  i
    for i in "$@"; do
        eval "$i"
    done
}

arr=(
  'ls "$dir"'
  'cat "$dir"/01_hello_world'
  '"$tree_cmd" "$dir"'
)

run_cmds "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: Definitely do not want to use eval, I tend to shy away from it for security reasons. Re: function method, Perfect, Thank you!